# how to send multiple files to a directory?

Tags: bash, split

I am spliting a song into several parts using split as follows:

```
split --bytes=1000000 Sleep.mp3 size
```

and I get several parts like this:

```
sizeaa 

sizeab

sizeac

sizead
```

the issue comes when I try to send this files generated to a directory called song like this:

```
split --bytes=1000000 Sleep.mp3 size > song/
```

I get:

```
-bash: song/: Is a directory
```

I would like to appreciate a way to achieve this.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot *send files to a directory*; at least not using I/O redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the directory as part of the output file

```
split --bytes=1000000 Sleep.mp3 song/size
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Make your destination directory your working directory

```
cd song
split --bytes=1000000 ../Sleep.mp3 size
```

Comment: Thanks this was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have to do this in two commands:

```
split --bytes=1000000 Sleep.mp3 size
mv size* song
```

Comment: I was thinking in the same but the problems comes if I have more files that its name begin when the word size, but thanks for the support.

Comment: contrapants suggestion above looks promising.